# Is there a way to get the google app engine developer tool to show post data?

Tags: google-app-engine, devserver

I'm having a heck of a time debugging my task queues in Google app engine as a bug in the task queue becomes very hard to track down as I don't know exactly what data is being posted.

I was hoping that I could get the dev_appserver.py application to display the POST data in the request line, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html) offers up a debug option, but it doesn't seem to print the post data.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) library to print the body of the request like this (if you're using [webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/)):

```
import logging
class YourRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info("body:\n%s" % self.request.body)
```